# Image of a complex region

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $A$ be the complex region that satisfies: $1\leq|z|\leq2 \wedge 0\leq\operatorname{Arg}z\leq\frac{1}{3}\pi$. Draw $A$ in the complex plane and describe the image of $A$ under $z\mapsto z^2$.

I was able to draw $A$, it's a disk centered at the origin bounded by the circle with radius 1 and radius 2, with the condition that it's between the line's with angle $0$ and $\frac{1}{3}\pi$.

I don't know the answer to the second question. Could someone give some help?

Comment: Hint: if we write $z \in A$ in polar form as $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $z^2 = r^2 e^{2i\theta}$.

Comment: @msteve so the image is $\left\{{z\in\mathbb{C}: 1\leq|z|\leq4 \wedge 0\leq\operatorname{Arg}z\leq \pi}\right\}$, since the modulus is squared and the angle is doubled under $z\mapsto z^2$?

Comment: @CauchytheDog $\pi$?

Comment: The argument is between $0$ and $2\pi/3$.

Comment: Oops, yes I understand. Thanks @msteve

Answer (score 2):

If $z = r e^{i \theta}$, with $1 \le r \le 2$ and $0 \le \theta \le \frac13 \pi$.

Then $z^2 = r^2 e^{i 2 \theta}$, with the same conditions for $r$ and $\theta$.

You know that the modulus of $z^2$ is $|z^2| = r^2$, and you know that its argument is $\arg z^2 = 2 \theta$. What are the conditions for the modulus and argument of $z^2$?

- From $1 \le r \le 2$, follows $1^2 \le r^2 \le 2^2$, or more simply $1 \le |z^2| \le 4$
- From $0 \le \theta \le \frac13 \pi$ follows $2 \cdot 0 \le 2 \cdot \theta \le 2 \cdot \frac13 \pi$, or more simply $0 \le \arg z^2 \le \frac23 \pi$

In conclusion, the image of $A$ is delimited by the circles with radius 1 and 4, and by the lines passing through the origin with angle 0 and $\frac23 \pi$.

Comment: Your inequality signs are backwards...

Comment: @zipirovich: oops, thanks for spotting that